# Mysql TEXT defined field not read

Tags: php, jquery, mysql

I have a MYSQL table that has a column defined as TEXT, when i reading the contents into PHP the result is that the data is not being pulled through.

my php code

```
SELECT establishments.name AS estName, 
            establishments.address AS estAddr,
            establishments.telephone_num AS estTel,
            establishments.description AS estDesc,
            establishments.Logo AS estLogo,
            establishments.title AS estTitle
      FROM bucurestideals1.establishments
      WHERE establishments.establishment_id ="'.$est_id.'"';
```

The table row has data so this is not an issue, i am reading the data using php as below:

```
    $.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: pass_url,
    dataType: 'jsonp',
    jsonp: 'jsoncallback',
    timeout: 5000,
    success: function (data, status) {

        // Assign the returned data to the page
        $.each(data, function(i,item)
        {


          alert(item.estDesc);



        });

    },
```

### Update: PHP Code

```
<?php

  header('Content-type: application/json');
  $est_id = $_GET['id'];
  $server = "*";
  $username = "*";
  $password = "*";
  $database = "";
  $con = mysql_connect($server, $username, $password) or die ("Could not connect: " . mysql_error());
  mysql_select_db($database, $con);
  $result = mysql_query($sql) or die ("Query error: " . mysql_error());
  $records = array();
  while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
  {
     $records[] = $row;
  }
  mysql_close($con);
  echo $_GET['jsoncallback'] . '(' . json_encode($records) . ');';
  ?>
```

Comment: The alert displays NULL

Comment: You are just showing your SQL request. Show us your PHP script in pass_url.

Comment: You havn't included the PHP code that the page is sending AJAX request to

Comment: Just try to execute the php file by hand and echo the output of the sql statment. At least you know if your scripts work then. Post your results.
Greetings

Comment: <?php header('Content-type: application/json'); $est_id = $_GET['id']; $server = "*"; $username = "*"; $password = "*"; $database = ""; $con = mysql_connect($server, $username, $password) or die ("Could not connect: " . mysql_error()); mysql_select_db($database, $con); $result = mysql_query($sql) or die ("Query error: " . mysql_error()); $records = array(); while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) { $records[] = $row; } mysql_close($con); echo $_GET['jsoncallback'].'(' . json_encode($records) . ');'; ?>

Answer (score 0):

You can probably remove the quotes from your where statement. If that is not the issue, can you post the php code that you use to execute the sql?

Comment: the pass_url script is fine i have checked this, no problems here, cheers

Comment: <?php
header('Content-type: application/json');

$est_id = $_GET['id'];

$server = "****";
$username = "****";
$password = "***";
$database = "**";

$con = mysql_connect($server, $username, $password) or die ("Could not connect: " . mysql_error());
mysql_select_db($database, $con);

$result = mysql_query($sql) or die ("Query error: " . mysql_error());

$records = array();

while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
 $records[] = $row;
}

mysql_close($con);

echo $_GET['jsoncallback'].'(' . json_encode($records) . ');';
?>

Comment: I had quotation marks in the column data, would anyone know how i can parse the result to include these?

Comment: *SELECT establishments.name AS estName, 
            establishments.address AS estAddr,
            establishments.telephone_num AS estTel,
            establishments.description AS estDesc,
            establishments.Logo AS estLogo,
            establishments.title AS estTitle
      FROM bucurestideals1.establishments
      WHERE establishments.establishment_id ='.$est_id.';*